# React Context API is slow

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, react-hooks, react-context

I'm experimenting with new Context API and hooks. I've created an app with sidebar (treeview), footer and main content page. I have a context provider

```
const ContextProvider: FunctionComponent = (props) => {

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(undefined);
const [treeNodes, setTreeNodes] = useState([]);

return (
    <MyContext.Provider
        value={{
            actions: {
                setSelected,
                setTreeNodes
            },
            selected,
            treeNodes
        }}
    >
        {props.children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
);
```

Im my content component I have a DetailsList (Office Fabric UI) with about 1000 items. When I click on the item in the list I want to update selected item in context. This works but it is really slow. It takes about 0,5-1 seconds to select item in the list. The list is virtualized. I have tried it on production build. Thing are a bit better but there is a noticable lag when clicking on list.
Footer is consuming myContext to display information about selected item.

Here is a bit of code from my component

```
const cntx = useContext(MyContext);

const onClick = (item) => {
    cntx.actions.setSelected(item);
};
```

Am I using the context wrong?

I've created a sample sandbox to demonstrate.. You can scroll to about 100-th index and click a couple of times to see how it gets unresponsive.

https://codesandbox.io/s/0m4nqxp4m0

Is this a problem with Fabric DetailsList? Does it reRender to many times? I believe the problem is with "complex" DatePicker component but I don't understand why does DetailsList get rerenderd? It's not using any of context properties within a render function. I would expect only Footer component to rerender on every context change

Comment: There is a lot of ``"The icon "calendar" was used but not registered. See http://aka.ms/fabric-icon-usage for more information. "`` warnings in console - im worried that this logging alone is causing the problem - please check that :) 

#edit - https://codesandbox.io/embed/llj1zk19rz

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm facing the same issue and the answer from @sonicmario is not helping

Answer (score 5):

Caveats
Because context uses reference identity to determine when to re-render, there are some gotchas that could trigger unintentional renders in consumers when a provider’s parent re-renders. For example, the code below will re-render all consumers every time the Provider re-renders because a new object is always created for value:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider value={{something: 'something'}}>
        <Toolbar />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

To get around this, lift the value into the parent’s state:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: {something: 'something'},
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider value={this.state.value}>
        <Toolbar />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats

Answer (score 1):

Memorize your selected item with useMemo to avoid creating an new object if you are referring to the same item. Then pass it in a dedicated context

Answer (score -1):

In your solution, whenever your component is rerendered, a new instance of `value` is passed down as a prop. This will trigger the re-rendering of the children as well.

If you use hooks, to prevent this, memoize the `value` object that you want to pass, in the `useMemo` or `useCallback` hook. In fact, this should be applied as a basic React practice to any of your components, not just a context component. Unless you're passing a primitive value (string, number, ...), don't create an instance or an inline function directly and pass it as a prop. Make sure the props you're passing don't get changed after each rendering cycle of the React component.